# Solution for EMI on signals in a connector?

Tags: pwm, connector, stepper-motor, emi-filtering, stepper-driver

I have PWM signal and PSU signals coming from switch mode PSU to our machine.
The motor drive boards that run the stepper motors in the machine are located in the PSU.
At the moment the outputs to motor windings are on separate connector but I need one connector for everything now.

To avoid any interference I need a D sub connector that filters any interference from signals and power on different pins of connector.

The frequency of PWM is 50 KHz (taken from the stepper drive datasheet) and based on that the capacitance of load (motor) is 1.6 nF and 10 nF for max operation voltage and min operating voltage respectively.

I have been looking for EMI filtered connectors but they are rare and expensive and maximum capacitance they have is 4000 PF. I am told that the attenuation still is very low for the 50Khz frequency that I want to filter out.
These are a notch filter so you don’t want to also filter out high frequency data as well.
Is there a way to supress motor noise?
Or are power line filters relevant?
I do need cable screening as well.

Has anyone worked out this kind of situation and has any advice about how to have one connector without any noise/interference issue?

Thanks

Comment: *To avoid any interference* - not possible. All you can do is prevent interference at source as much as you can and make those circuits that might be susceptible as resilient as possible and, both of these actions is not achieved by choosing a different connector.

Comment: If that one connector carries DC power, which powers the stepper boards located by each motor, the noise will be greatly reduced.

Comment: What is an EMI filtered connector? You mean shielded? or what?

Comment: yes, EMi filtered connector is a connector with C-type or PI-type filtering that would attenuate noise and should shield interference.